Intellisense not working for object destructuring in Visual Studio Code
The intellisense of VSCode doesn't work when destructuring an object, it returns any as the type, no matter what.
I tried:
/**
 * @returns {{name:String,surname:String}}
 */
function Test(){
 return {name:"John",surname:"Doe"};
}
const {name,surname} = Test(); // Intellisense shows "any" for both 

I was expecting to get proper type information, in this case, string.

I can't reproduce this. VSCode shows the types as string for me.

@Unmitigated It shows as any for me. Version: 1.92.0, MacOS (ARM). Remember this is JSDoc syntax, not TypeScript Syntax.

@connexo I am aware; I directly copied the code into a new .js file.

It helps to create a type definition:
/**
 *
 * @typedef {Object} NameType
 * @prop {'John'} name
 * @prop {'Doe'} surname
 */

/**
 * @returns {NameType}
 */
function Test() {
  return { name: 'John', surname: 'Doe' };
}
const { name, surname } = Test(); // Intellisense shows the proper type for both



Isn't there a way to add it to vscode automatically?

None that I know of.
